# svmono array padding

Tags: spacing, arrays, sv-classes

The svmono class (available [here](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0)) butchers spacing inside arrays; compare

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{|l|}
text
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

to the same in the `article` class. There is very little space between the left line of the array and the text. Does anyone know which length might be involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between the vertical rules and cell contents is specified by `\arraycolsep` in the `array` environment. Change this to your liking using

```
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{<len>}
```

Default in the document class seems to be `1.5pt`, compared to `5pt` in [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls).